# alternate to request.header in angular

Tags: java, angular, servlets

we have a web app in jsp and servlets and have a login page outside control of the code but when a user logins to app we get login id using request.getheader(loginid). now we are shifting front end code to Angular and in Angular code we need the login id. I dont know how we are going to pass login id to anguar code. it is required in angular code because that login id is used in further http calls.
can anyone please suggest on how to pass/get login id to angular.

Comment: A possible rabbit hole you might want to consider going down is looking at iframes and local storage. A lot of people use a strategy like that for using adaljs in their angular apps. Cheers